# Is there a way to disable user registration in Keycloak realm's local database as part of first broker login?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-gatekeeper

As per Keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_identity_broker_oidc) when the user is logs in through identity brokering, Keycloak checks and creates user in realms local database as part of First Broker Login Flow.

Is there a way to disable user onboarding in Keycloak local database and always check for the authentication from IDP instead of local database?

And what is the rationale behind this default Keycloak implementation as there are some basic issues like user data synchronisation between Keycloak and IDP?